# Java: BufferedReader and OutputStream

Tags: java

I've got the following code, I'm trying to  send data text by sockets. But when I try to send via `PrintWriter`, my client does nothing and it stops at `in.readLine()`. However when I use simply OutputStream and  send it as bytes, my client doesn't have any problem with reading. Is it possible to as I want ?

```
        out = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("SERVER-THREAD: IP "
                    + sock.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());
            out.write(marshall() + "\n");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
```

//Client

```
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
            out = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());

            while (updateList) {
                System.out.println("Before");
                String inputip = in.readLine();
                System.out.println("CLIENT: " + inputip);
                //unmarshall(in);
                System.out.println("After");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
```

Comment: Why don't you show us the code that doesn't work, instead of showing us the code that works?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`PrintWriter` buffers the data to be written so it will not do so until the buffer is full. You need to call flush here

```
out.flush();
```

Comment: Yep. The documentation says: *if automatic flushing is enabled it will be done only when one of the println, printf, or format methods is invoked, rather than whenever a newline character happens to be output.*

Answer (score 3):

When you perform a readLine() it waits until it has a read a whole line. i.e. a new line.

Your send is sending text without a newline so the receive waits for something which will not happen.

A more basic problem is that you are mixing text and binary which is more likely to confuse than be useful.

I suggest you write text with PrintWriter.println() which you can read with BufferedReader.readLine().